# Why did Narcissa think Harry knew if Draco was dead or alive?

Tags: harry-potter

When Voldemort did the Killing Curse on Harry in *The Deathly Hallows Part 2* and he asked Narcissa to see if Harry was dead, and she asked if Draco was dead - why did she think Harry knew if he was alive or not? It's not like they're brothers.

Comment: Presumably because Harry was leader of Voldemort's opposition. Also he came from the castle which was Draco's last know location as he did not exited Hogwarts with rest of Slytherin students. And last maybe Narcisa thought that Harry did something to Draco knowing hatred of each other

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic ninja'd :-)

Comment: @randal'thor We posted answer at same time :D Anyway I would advise sluger to read books, as you sad on previous question Films are terrible and should not think them and cannon.

Comment: Dude im on my third time reading the series

Comment: @sluger than start asking questions considering books not films, as books are consider canon. 90% of your questions in last hour can be answered by reading the books. With exception of this question. Altho anyone rational enough could understand the answer

Comment: I'd be tempted to answer "Because he did know."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**She wasn't *sure* Harry would know, but he was more likely to know than anyone else there.**

He'd been on the inside of Hogwarts, with the defenders, and she knew Draco was also inside. Stuck in the Death Eater camp, she had no way of knowing what was happening to Draco or even of getting in contact with anyone who knew - until Harry came along. He was the only person in that clearing who might have a chance of knowing whether Draco was alive or dead, so she took that chance and asked him.

Comment: Possibly a better question would be why she trusted his answer. Answering anything but yes would have been pure suicide for Harry, and even if he hadn’t had the faintest idea what, if anything, had happened to Draco, he would probably have said yes just to cling to any hope that he would not be given away immediately. Surely an otherwise intelligent woman like Narcissa (who must have done a lot of quick thinking in those few seconds when she was examining Harry) must have realised this. I don’t suppose distrusting him would make getting Draco back more likely, though…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Mothers love knows not bounds, as Lily proved it. Even if there was slightest chance that Draco was alive she had to take it. Also Dark Lord thought that Draco deflected and joined forces with Harry, if Dark Lord won it is no likely that Draco would be spared

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet She was desperate, and clinging to any slight thread of hope she could find. She'd rather live in hope that he was telling the truth than convince herself rationally that there was no reason he should be. You say "an otherwise intelligent woman", but temporary loss of one's reasoning abilities when one's loved ones are in danger is ... not unknown.

Comment: @Vanja What makes you say Voldemort thought Draco had defected? Is there something that implies this that I’m simply not remembering? Certainly, he cared little for Draco by this time, but is it ever implied that he believed Draco had joined Harry?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It is implied from Dark Lord himself in conversion with Lucius “My Lord. . . please. . . my son. . . ” “If your son is dead, Lucius, it is not my fault. He did not come and join me, like the rest of the Slytherins. Perhaps he has decided to befriend Harry Potter?” “No—never,” whispered Malfoy. “You must hope not.” –

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not sure I agree. To me, Narcissa stopping to ask Harry about Draco was a sign that she believed Harry would have made sure Draco didn't die unnecessarily. I took that show of trust as an implication that her heart was already not in Voldemort's war. We might never know for sure, but my guess is that she had been planning to let Harry escape either way.

Comment: @Misha Rosnach - I think she is definitely already in "We made the wrong choice" mode since it became so clear that Voldemort's interest in her son was a punishment for her family and that his death was perfectly acceptable to Voldemort.

Comment: @ThruGog The moment she surreptitiously asks Harry about Draco is where we see direct evidence of her not being truly on Voldemort's side.  We get no similar evidence with Draco's father.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Harry was never much of an Occlumens, even at the best of times.  She may have been confident in her ability to tell if he was lying.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's actually a very good point that I hadn't considered at all. Bellatrix is obviously not much of a Legilimens (at least not in the atrium of the Ministry—she doesn't recognise that Harry is telling the truth about the Prophecy shattering), but then Narcissa is very different from her sister, and she seems more the type who would be an accomplished Legilimens.